mountpoint-s3 change region
In the AWS project: mountpoint-s3 https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3#getting-started, how do I set the region?
In my ~/.sso/config file - the region is set to us-west-2 but when I try to mount a S3 bucket, it errors as following (note s3-bucket is just an example name):
coder@abc:~/s3$ mount-s3 s3-bucket .
Error: Failed to create S3 client

Caused by:
    0: initial ListObjectsV2 failed for bucket kf-vikas in region us-east-1
    1: Client error
    2: No signing credentials found
Error: Failed to create mount process

I am able to run other s3 commands (such as following):
aws s3 ls s3://s3-bucket


I have a similar issue, did you manage to solve it

@reham501 - no.
